# Spring boot on Azure produces internal server error

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot

I want to deploy my jar on microsoft azure but it shows me an internal server error. the jar works on my pc fine, i added the following web.config file to my wwwroot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar ";%HOME%\site\wwwroot\myjar.jar";">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately it does not work... I want to deploy it on a webApp in azure

Comment: What do the logs show?

Comment: Good question, where can i find them?

Comment: I got the following error: Configuration file is not well formated on arguments=&quot;-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\sds-backend-0.0.1.jar&quot;&quot; &gt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a non-well formated xml file... now it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar %HOME%\site\wwwroot\myjar.jar" >
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```